# Check if current user is in a specific group if so execute some code else quit

Tags: python, if-statement, active-directory, ldap3

I am pretty new to python and active directory.
I used a little bit of ldap3 to search the AD for the members of the group.

1. Can I somehow check if the current user is in a specific AD group and if that is the case some more code executes?
2. Is there a better way to get the distinguishedName, server connection etc.?
3. Also i would like to not use any passwords or login information since i just dont want it to be in the code if that is even possible

The main problem for me is currently that i dont know and dont understand how to check for membership or if thats even possible

This is the Code i have now:

```py
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL
import ctypes

pw = '*********'

print()


def get_data(extended_name_format: int):
    get_user_name_ex = ctypes.windll.secur32.GetUserNameExW
    data = extended_name_format

    size = ctypes.pointer(ctypes.c_ulong(0))
    get_user_name_ex(data, None, size)

    name_buffer = ctypes.create_unicode_buffer(size.contents.value)
    get_user_name_ex(data, name_buffer, size)
    return name_buffer.value


displayName = get_data(3)
distinguishedName = get_data(1)
print(displayName)
print(distinguishedName)
print()

server = Server('**dom1.***.***', get_info=ALL)
conn = Connection(server, auto_bind=True)
print(conn)

entries = conn.extend.standard.paged_search('CN=***,OU=***,OU=***,OU=***,DC=***,DC=***', '(member=*)', attributes=['member'], paged_size=5)
for entry in entries:
    print(entry)

if distinguishedName == entries:
    print('yay')
else:
    print('nope')
```

Comment: I think this question is well-presented, but you need to show some work about what you've _done_ to receive actionable help.  Were you confused about `ldap3` documentation?  Did you get an error message? etc.

Comment: I dont really get an error message the code works like it is but i do not know how to check for membership and i just dont find anything useful anywhere.
@MaximilianBurszley

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `member` attribute of a group contains the "distinguished name" of each member. That is a format that looks like `CN=SomeUser,OU=Users,DC=example,DC=com`.

You're already using [`GetUserNameExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/nf-secext-getusernameexw) to get the username. You can use that to get the distinguished name by passing a value of `1` for the `NameFormat` parameter, which corresponds to [`NameFullyQualifiedDN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/secext/ne-secext-extended_name_format).

Comment: I think i already do that. My value `adPath` is the distinguished name of the user.
Can i just do some sort of:
```python
if adPath == entry:

```

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Comment: I did this but that did not work:

```python
if distinguishedName == entries:
print('yay')
else:
print('nope')
```
and when i swap entries with entry it still always gives out "nope" even tho it should be correct since i have that role
And my code doesnt really work if i delete the login information for the server thats another thing i try to do beacuse i just dont want to have my password somewhere in the code

Comment: `distinguishedName == entries` will always be false because you're comparing a string to an array. You need to check if the array contains the string. Just search Google and I'm sure you can find an example of that.